# How to schedule local notification varying time slot?

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, localnotification

I need to fire a local notification which is decided by the end user.

I provide 8/9 options to the user for selecting at least one of below time duration.
20 minutes , 25 minutes till 60 minutes.

Again user provides the starting time.

Consider the time duration is morning 6.28 to night 11.37

The expected tasks performed by the local notification is

show a local notification after every 20 minutes between the duration of 6.28 am to 11.37 pm.

first notification will come at 6.48 am. And till its 11.37 . No notification should come after 11.37.

Is there any way ?

Answer (score 1):

`UILocalNotification` has a [`repeatInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/repeatInterval) property which you'd normally use to create recurring notifications. Unfortunately, it does not offer the flexibility you need - you can use repeat intervals of 1 minute, 1 hour, but nothing in between. And there's also no 'end date' option.

The only other option is to create multiple notifications, each firing only once. Keep in mind that there is a maximum of 64 notifications per app. With a minimum interval of 20 minutes, this covers 21 hours and 20 minutes of notifications.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking to create a another notification adding 20 mins to the current time. I have one  question in mind how snoozing of alarm clock works. May be that idea will help me to achieve  my need

Comment: Found the solution. I ll cancel all the notification and reschedule them once I get the any local notification.

Answer (score -1):

UILocalNotification has repeatInterval property.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotif.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
```

Try above code.

Comment: will it  create notification after each 25 minutes ?.

Comment: That doesn't work, you cannot specify the number of minutes.

Comment: Found a way solution .Whenever I get notification I should cancel all the notification and reschedule  it again. This works perfectly thought codes gets little messy.